# error in simple list adapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to display multiple list view using simple list adapter but my application crashes when I'm going to the set the adapter here is my code;

my logcat view is this when my program crashes

```
11-11 09:03:06.147: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(789): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    11-11 09:03:06.147: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(789): CheckJNI is ON
    11-11 09:03:06.907: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(789): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    11-11 09:03:06.937: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(789): Shutting down VM
    11-11 09:03:06.957: DEBUG/dalvikvm(789): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+1ms
    11-11 09:03:06.957: DEBUG/dalvikvm(789): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    11-11 09:03:06.987: INFO/AndroidRuntime(789): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
    11-11 09:03:07.547: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(799): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    11-11 09:03:07.547: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(799): CheckJNI is ON
    11-11 09:03:08.267: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(799): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
    11-11 09:03:08.307: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package com.flds uid=10052
    11-11 09:03:08.307: INFO/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 779 SIG: 9
    11-11 09:03:08.457: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.flds/.TestssActivity } from pid 799
    11-11 09:03:08.487: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(799): Shutting down VM
    11-11 09:03:08.507: DEBUG/dalvikvm(799): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 322K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+2ms
    11-11 09:03:08.537: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Start proc com.flds for activity com.flds/.TestssActivity: pid=808 uid=10052 gids={}
    11-11 09:03:08.547: WARN/InputManagerService(68): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4059a5e8
    11-11 09:03:08.577: INFO/AndroidRuntime(799): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

code

```
public class TestssActivity extends Activity
{

    private SimpleAdapter mSchedule;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SCHEDULE);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("train", "101");
        map.put("from", "6:30 AM");
        map.put("to", "7:40 AM");
        mylist.add(map);


       mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL});
       list.setAdapter(mSchedule);

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, there should be a crash log stacktrace in it. It's usually in red and has the tag `AndroidRuntime`.

Comment: Thanks. But thats not what we are looking for. It's hard to spot if you dont know what to search. A few examples: It should look like [this](http://blog.echooff.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/screenshot1.png) or [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/classnotfoundex.png/). Basically something with the keyword `Exception`.

Comment: this is the exact logcat view which i have pasted

Comment: nothing come in red here but my application crashed by saying application has been stopeed unexpectedly

Comment: moreover m following this tutorial infact i have copied the code from here  "http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/"

Answer (score 0):

There is no setContentView(...

ListView is not found because there is no such.

The blog page was removed. Or wrong link.